# interpretation for $f(x)=f(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Is there any interpretation geometric may be for a function that satisfies

$
f(x)= f(\frac{1}{x})\; \; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^* $

Is it of kind $f(x)= f(g(x))$ ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, it's a function $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\to\text{somewhere}$ such that $f\circ \exp$ and $f\circ(-\exp)$ are even.

Comment: is there any relation between the graph of f and of $\frac{1}{x}$ ?

Comment: I do not know, tbh.

Comment: Just as even functions $f(x)=f(-x)$ are symmetric about $0$, then $f(x)=f(x^{-1})$ are symmetric about $1$, in the sense that everything above $1$ is "reflected" into $(0,1)$.

Comment: Stereographic projection gives a geometric interpretation of $f(1/x)$ on the Riemann sphere as it reverses the role of $0$ and $\infty$, and inverts the sphere. Since the reals are a subset of the complex numbers they can be interpreted this way as well.

Comment: I think you can define $f$ arbitrarily on $[1, \infty)$. Then on $(0,1]$ it would look like a reflection across the line $x=1$, "compressed" to fit. Similar for negative $x$.

Comment: Seems like a Schröder's equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%27s_equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us think of that property in group-theoretic terms. We have a function $f\colon \mathbb R_{>0}\to \mathbb R$ such that
$$\tag{1}
f(t)=f(t^{-1}), \qquad \forall t >0.$$
The domain $(\mathbb R_{>0}, \cdot)$ is a group, and (1) tells us that $f$ is invariant under the operation $t\mapsto t^{-1}$.

For the more familiar group $(\mathbb R, +)$, the corresponding operation would be $x\mapsto -x$. So, the property analogous to (1) for a function $g\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ would be
$$\tag{2}
g(x)=g(-x), \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb R,$$
which is a familiar one, as it expresses that $g$ is an even function.

Actually, (1) and (2) are equivalent. Indeed, the change of variable
$$t=e^x$$
is an isomorphism of the groups $(\mathbb R, +)$ and $(\mathbb R_{>0}, \cdot)$. Now, if $f$ satisfies (1), then denoting
$$
g(x):=f(e^x), $$
we see that $g$ satisfies (2). Conversely, if $g$ satisfies (2), then denoting
$$
f(t)=g(\log t) $$
we see that $f$ satisfies (1).

**Conclusion**. We can say that a function $f$ satisfying the property (1) is *even* in the group $(\mathbb R_{>0}, \cdot)$.

**P.S.** I hadn't read the comments before posting. I see that various users, such as Gae.S and Chrystomath, proposed this exact same idea.